# C# Syntax analyze: get type members

Tags: c#, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree, codedom

I want to analyze a project written in C#. 
I need to get all classes with name "ClassFoo", which has method "MethodFoo" with parameter of type "int".

In pseudocode:

```
var slnFiles = new List<string>{"File1.cs","File2.cs"};
var codeDom = new CodeDomProvider(slnFiles);
foreach(domTree in codeDom)
{
    var types = domTree.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("ClassFoo"));
    foreach(t in types)
    {
         t.GetMembers().Where( x=>x.IsMethod() && x.Name =="MethodFoo" x.Parameters.Contains(y=>y.Type.Name == "int"))
    }

}
```

I've read about 'CodeDom' but i found only way to load a file and compile it, when i need analyze it.
Also,  my target can be achieved with help of reflection, but i'm searching a way to  analyze the C# file without compiling.

Comment: Have you considered using the Roslyn API?

Comment: Thank you @dymanoid! Looks like, It works for me.